# How is this bootbox even created?

Tags: javascript, html, bootbox

I need to add some more inputs in a bootbox (which is in the picture bellow). However, I'm not able to find the html that "made it"

The `message` parameter it's filled with  `"<div class='dv_content'></div>"` and nothing else

I don't know how this message can become this bootbox with so many inputs. For that I need you help understanding something that could be quite basic for some, but it isn't for me.

[image]

---

### Let me give you more context

As you can see in the picture, there is a button. Once the button is clicked the bootbox is displayed.
The function that it is called when the button is clicked is the following

[image]

As it is shown in the function body, it is creating a bootbox. Thus the question arises again. How can something as simple as `"<div class='dv_content'></div>"` can create that enormous bootbox?

Comment: I suspect it is in the `form_agend()` function.

Comment: hmmm, let me comment it on the code to see what happends. I mean, when i read the function it didn't seem

Comment: well... you're right. Thanks!

Comment: I added my response as an answer since it answered the question of whee in the code is the form being added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the code provided, it looks like it will be most likely be in `form_agend()`. The function can reference the variable as well as create event listeners for when the modal has opened and is visible or is in the process of opening.